# AVAsset 'tracksWithMediaType' return an empty array?(audio)

Tags: ios, audio, composite, avasset

I want to composite two audio by using `AVAssetExportSession`.When I use `AVAsset` to get track by using '`tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio`',I got an empty array.
  These audio file are recorded by '`AVAudioRecorder`' and they have `.aac` extensions.
  The code I used to get track:

```
 AVAsset * asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:model.localPath]];

 NSArray * tracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

 AVAssetTrack * track = nil;
 if (tracks.count) {
     track = tracks[0];
 }
```

The setting to init `AVAudioRecorder`:

```
AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];


NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithFloat:11025.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];//44100.0
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey: AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMax] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
```

I also try other .`mp3` file to get track,but it is an empty array.
  The localpath of audio file is:

```
  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDAB48C4-A233-4B4C-B3B7-5F66AE076239/Documents/media/1497494042.aac
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.
  The localpath is wrong!The correct path should be this "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDAB48C4-A233-4B4C-B3B7-5F66AE076239/Documents/media/1497494042.aac"

Comment: Your had to use `fileURLWithPath:` instead of `URLWithString:`.